# Receive Mail with Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a simple project in spring integration that is attempting to receive mail:

```
@Service
public class MailReceiverService implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Bean
    TestMailServer.ImapServer imapServer() {
        return TestMailServer.imap(0);
    }

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MailReceiverService.class);

    public static void manageMessage() {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ac =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/integration/gmail-imap-idle-config.xml");
    DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);


            inputChannel.subscribe(message -> {
                logger.info("Message: " + message);
            });



  }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        manageMessage();
    }


}
```

The gmail-imap-idle-config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail https://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util https://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">

    <int:channel id="receiveChannel" />
    <int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
            store-uri="imaps://username:password@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox"
            channel="receiveChannel"
            auto-startup="true"
            should-delete-messages="false"
            should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
            java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>

    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
    </util:properties>

</beans>
```

However when I run it I get this message:

Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'

And it shuts down!  any suggestions on how to get this working?
Thanks!

Comment: In your code method `manageMessage()`, called from `run(String... args)` method, will get executed after application is fully started because `MailReceiverService` implements `CommandLineRunner` but spring creates a subscriber for `errorChannel` if `errorChannel` is explicitly not defined and it happens when context is getting ready. 
It seems like your application context is not coming up properly. Can you please share the complete log, pom and other configurations(if any) for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that you don't keep an application alive. The `<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>` initiates a long-running process on the background. But when you start your application, you step immediately away from the main thread and that one just exits. In the meantime you get a message from email box, but a subscriber for the `receiveChannel` is gone already because your application in a closing state according a main thread behavior.

Consider to have some barrier in that `run()` do not the main thread to exit.

In samples we typically have something like this:

```
System.out.println("Hit 'Enter' to terminate");
System.in.read();
ctx.close();
```

This way you won't let a JVM to exit and therefore will receive emails until you terminate the application.